# Why second shell script(nohup) not triggered after first script?

Tags: linux, shell, nohup

I have two shell scripts abc.sh and def.sh(which just echos something).
Third script ghi.sh has:

```
nohup /home/tomcat/automation/abc.sh &
sleep 20
nohup /home/tomcat/automation/def.sh &
```

After running ghi.sh, abc.sh is triggered and hangs; def.sh is not triggered at all. How can I fix this issue.

Comment: Does any of the scripts (commands therein) need to read from stdin?

Comment: no...i am just doing echo 'hello' in one and echo 'world' in the other

Answer (score 0):

My output on reproducing the issue:

```
 I ran : abc.txt
 I am also running def.sh
```

Does def.sh has executable permission?
Add set -x in all files and see where its getting stuck.